# DropdownList not refreshing in IE11 but refreshes with Enterpise mode

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox

I have DropdownList in my ASP.NET webform which does not autopostback on change.

It works if I select Enterprise Mode or I open it in Firefox.

What am I missing here?

Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FormatsDropDownList"
                runat="server"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="FormatsDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Item1" Value="Value1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Item2" Value="Value2"></asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Did you get this working? If so, how? If not, what's the browser mode and document mode in IE when it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Net 4.0:

Follow the steps found here:
http://rikter.com/articles/2013/12/internet-explorer-11-and-asp-net/

*But Use this browser file found here for step 1:
http://blogs.telerik.com/docs/default-source/marinbratanov_files/telerik_ie11_browser_file_fix.zip?sfvrsn=2

Once I put this new file in my app_browsers folder, cleared temp files, ran regbrowsers.exe and did IIS reset, the site works in IE 11 without compatibility mode on.